# Regex negative match in middle of string

Tags: php, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have these strings (checking every line separately):

```
adminUpdate
adminDeleteEx
adminEditXe
adminExclude
listWebsite
listEx
```

Now I want to match anything that starts with `admin` but does not ends with `Ex` (case-insensitive)

So after applying regex I must match:

```
adminUpdate
adminEditXe
adminExclude
```

[My current regex is `/^admin[a-z]+(?!ex)$/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/bU2jJ7/4) but it matches anything that starts with `admin`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a slight change:

```
/^admin[a-z]+(?<!ex)$/gi
               ^
```

Turn your look-ahead into a look-behind.

It is quite hard to explain in the current form. Basically, you need to reach the end of the string `$` for the regex to match, and when it happens, `(?!ex)` is at the end of the string, so it can't see anything ahead. However, since we are at the end of the string, we can use a look-behind `(?<!ex)` to check whether the string ends with `ex` or not.

Since look-around is zero-width, we can swap the position of `(?<!ex)` and `$` without changing the meaning (it does change how the engine searches for the matched string, though):

```
/^admin[a-z]+$(?<!ex)/gi
```

It is counter-intuitive to write it this way, but easier to see where my argument goes.

Another way to look at it is: due to the fact that `(?!ex)` and `$` are zero-width assertion, they are checked at the same position, and being at the end of the string `$`  implies you won't see anything ahead.

Comment: Thx, it's working. Can you explain why look-ahead is not working in here?

Comment: @Justinas: I added explanation, but it is quite a high level explanation. You might want to use the regex debugger feature on regex101 to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?!.*Ex$)admin.*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/23

```
$re = ""^(?!.*Ex$)admin.*$"m";
$str = "adminUpdate\nadminDeleteEx\nadminEditXe\nadminExclude\nlistWebsite\nlistEx";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```